# jquery $.ajax call to WCF returns 404 not found error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, wcf

I am new to WCF services. I just wanted to learn WCF with $.ajax call so created a test application which has two projects 1. WcfService1 project of Wcf service and another Client asp.net application to consume that service. **When I try making ajax call to service error 404 (not found) is displayed** **When I am running WCF service everything looks OK. Even when I try calling it from Client C# file, everything is OK.**. The code for Client is

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
Enter a number here : &nbsp &nbsp<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtbox"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnClick" OnClick="btnClick_Click" Text="ClickMe"/>
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#txtbox').on("keyup", function () {
        debugger;
        var txt = parseInt($(this).val());
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:2393/Service1.svc/GetData",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType:"jsonp",
            data: JSON.stringify({ value: txt }),
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                console.log(data.d);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

I made a simple ajax call to WcfService which will simply echo the entered number back.
My client Web.config file is

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>

<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:2393/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

My WcfService web.config, interface(contract) followed by WcfService implementation is as below

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
 </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings />
<client />
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

Service Contract

```
namespace WcfService1
{
  [ServiceContract]
   public interface IService1
  {
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetData/{value}",
   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)] 
    string GetData(int value);
  }   
}
```

Service implementation

```
namespace WcfService1
{    
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
}
}
```

please guide me wherever I am wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have both the projects inside the same solution. So how do I run Wcf service project.

Comment: You are sending POST request but your wcf is having WebGet attribute.

Comment: I tried changing WebGet attribute to [WebInvoke(Method="POST", RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json )] but didn't workout for me